# Java deployment process

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, jboss

Maybe it's a stupid question but I want to know how it works. I'm working on NetBeans and I have a project that I successfuly built and run. What I understand is that when I deploy a project, the IDE will create a file `.war` in a target folder. This war is created because of all the dependencies read with Maven from the pom.xml. For example, in my project, a project called pro1 have a dependency with an other project called pro2. So during the build, the .war will contain all the files, from pro1 and pro2. That's what I understand, so am I right ?

And an other question about the link where I can find the application. When I deploy the project, I want to go on my browser and look if what I developped is correct. But I don't find the link to access it. I thought it was localhost:8080/nameofmyproject but it doesn't work. The server is working because when I go on localhost:8080, I have the JBoss page. What did I miss please ?

Comment: Have a look at your web.xml, application.xml (in case of an ear) or jboss-web.xml. What you are looking for is the context root. AFAIK jboss uses the war's name (without the .war) extension by default, so check the exact spelling (try to keep whitespace out of that name).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks ! So, if the .war file is called `projectDeploy.war`, I will access by localhost:8080/projectDeploy ?

Comment: @Thomas I have a jboss-web.xml AND a web.xml. I can see the context root but I don't see in which order I have to put them. Can you help me please ?

Comment: AFAIK jboss-web.xml will override web.xml so if you put a context root there it should be sufficient.

Comment: @Thomas Something like localhost:8080/contextRoot ? But it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: No, have a look at how you define that in jboss-web.xml and make sure the file is included in the war. It would look like `<context-root>/whatever</context-root>` and you'd then use `http://localhost:8080/whatever`.

Comment: @Thomas Yea, that's what I meant with "contextRoot". But it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Thomas I checked and it's included in the .war